# Can a WebP file contain multiple images like TIFF?

Tags: imagemagick, tiff, webp

TIFF has multipage capability to store more than one image.
Does WebP (or other bitmap formats) have this ability as well?
I'm not talking about animations - the use case would be to store hires lossy or lossless bitmap data, just like in TIFF.

I tried `convert multipage.tiff multipage.webp`, but the result is an animation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a WebP file can contain only a single image, although the image may be animated (that is, the image may have multiple frames to be displayed in sequence with a delay between frames).

The WebP format is documented here:

https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container

There seems to be no provision for a WebP file to contain multiple pages or multiple static images.  The word "page" is not found in the specification.  There is also no mention of pages or multiple images in the [WebP FAQ](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/faq).